# assign a value in switch() different from the parameter passed in R

Tags: r, switch-statement

I do not fully understand switch() in R, I have seen examples like:

```
newCat <- switch(EXPR = category,
       cat1   = catX,
       cat2   = catX,
       cat3   = catY,
       cat4   = catY,
       cat5   = catZ,
       cat6   = catZ,
       "not available")
```

But, what I need is, given a parameter, to do something different...

I am trying to rewrite this into a case:

```
sample<-function(M,meth)
{

  if (meth=="sin_low" || meth=="sin_high")
  {
    d<-samplesin(M)
  }
  if (meth=="GP" || meth ="GP_high")
  {
    d<-sampleGP(M)
  }
  return(d)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of what you are trying to do and show the expected output based on that?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a function like `vswitch` or `nif` in the `kit` package on CRAN. Check the documentation. If it does not help, please let me know.